# The uploaded file value gets deleted once the page is re-submitted with incomplete inputs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like the page to saves the uploaded file even if the submit button is clicked at the time where not all the form is filled unless all the form is completed.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cvURL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.cvURL, new { type = "file" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cvURL)
        </div>
    </div>




public ActionResult RegisterCandidates(CandidateRegisteration can, HttpPostedFileBase cvURL)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (CheckFileType(cvURL.FileName))
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(cvURL.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/CVuploads"), fileName);
            can.cvURL = cvURL.FileName;
            cvURL.SaveAs(path);
            db.CandidateRegisteration.Add(can);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.emailExists = "Not Right extention";
        }

    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: It gets deleted from `~/CVuploads`?

Comment: no from the actual page for example if the form inputs has wrong details or an existed username and I click submit the cv that was uploaded gets deleted where the other fields or inputs their values stays there on the form

Comment: Maybe try setting the "value"... something like this: ...new { type = "file", value="@Model.cvURL.FileName" }

Comment: yes it worked like that